# NgTable using API and groupBy with a global filter

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I'm having difficulty with NgTable, however the functionality I'm looking for may be a limitation on the table framework.

I'm using an API call within the getData, and the data is being grouped (via the groupBy property in the settings param).

I want to be able to use a global filter on the data, I can't seem to get it work with grouping. There's two examples, except they don't mix:

Grouping: http://ng-table.com/#/grouping/demo-grouping-basic
Global filtering: http://ng-table.com/#/filtering/demo-api

Any suggestions?

Table declaration/config

```
$scope.tableNotesParams = new ngTableParams({
    page: 1,   // show first page
    count: 10,  // count per page: use total result set in this case,
    sorting: {
        created_at: 'desc'
    }
}, {
    groupBy: function( note ) {
        return moment( note.created_at ).format( 'YYYY' );
    },
    getData: function ( $defer, params ) {

        $scope.request.notes.state = 'started';
        $scope.request.notes.notesSpinner = true;

        var offset = params.count() * ( params.page() - 1 );

        // Default
        var urlQueryParams = {
            'email': member.accounts.email,
            'offset': offset,
            'limit': params.count() || 10
        };

        notesApiService.getNotes( urlQueryParams ).then( function ( results ) {

            $scope.notes = results.data;
            $scope.noteMembers = extractionService.getAllUniqueMembers( $scope.notes );

            // Get the range values, expecting value to be: items 1-10/655
            var noteHeaders      = results.headers();
            var notesRangeValues = noteHeaders['content-range'].match( /(\d{1,})/g );

            $scope.tableNotesMetaData = {
                offsetStart: notesRangeValues[0] || 0,
                offsetEnd  : notesRangeValues[1] || 0,
                totalCount : notesRangeValues[2] || 0
            };

            // Update parent controller count
            $scope.tabs.notes.count = notesRangeValues[2] || 0;

            // Update the total
            params.total( $scope.tableNotesMetaData.totalCount );


            var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
                              $filter('orderBy')($scope.notes, params.orderBy()) :
                              $scope.notes;


            $defer.resolve( orderedData );

            $scope.request.notes.state = 'completed';
            $scope.request.notes.notesSpinner = false;

        });

    }
});
```

**Edit**:

The filtering example for a global filter doesn't do anything to the grouped data:

```js
function applyGlobalSearch(){
  var term = self.globalSearchTerm;
  if (self.isInvertedSearch){
    term = "!" + term;
  }
  self.tableParams.filter({ $: term });
}
```

Comment: where's the specific problem with grouping?

Comment: Any progress? more questions?

Comment: After further review, it looks like the whole architecture should change.
I appreciate the help! This is kind of let down by the people running NgTable though, there's no way to globally handle filtering grouped data without building around/outside the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's performant to query your `notesApiService.getNotes()` in the `getData()`-function, but whatever. Since we don't have the HTML or a JSBin to work with, it's mostly guestimate:

```
notesApiService.getNotes( urlQueryParams ).then( function ( results ) {
    var term = $scope.globalSearchTerm.toLowerCase();
    if (term.length == 0) {
        $scope.notes = angular.copy(results.data, []);
    } else if (term.length > 1) {
        $scope.notes = results.data.filter(function(item) {
            var val = JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase();
            return (val.indexOf(term) != -1);
        });
    }
```